# Comparing two numpy arrays of different length

Tags: python, numpy

I need to find the indices of the first less than or equal occurrence of elements of one array in another array.  One way that works is this:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([10,7,2,0])
b = numpy.array([10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1])
indices = [numpy.where(a<=x)[0][0] for x in b]
```

*indices* has the value [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3], which is what I need.  The problem of course, is that python "for" loop is slow and my arrays might have millions of elements.  Is there any numpy trick for this?  This doesn't work because they arrays are not of the same length:

```
indices = numpy.where(a<=b) #XXX: raises an exception
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide reasonable sizes for `a` and `b`? The timings of methods are heavily influenced by this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This may be a special case, but you should be able to use numpy [digitize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html). The caveat here is the bins must be monotonically decreasing or increasing.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.array([10,7,2,0])
>>> b = numpy.array([10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1])

>>> indices = [numpy.where(a<=x)[0][0] for x in b]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]

>>> numpy.digitize(b,a)
array([0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3])
```

---

Setup for the timing test:

```
a = np.arange(50)[::-1]

b = np.random.randint(0,50,1E3)

np.allclose([np.where(a<=x)[0][0] for x in b],np.digitize(b,a))
Out[55]: True
```

Some timings:

```
%timeit [np.where(a<=x)[0][0] for x in b]
100 loops, best of 3: 4.97 ms per loop

%timeit np.digitize(b,a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 48.1 µs per loop
```

Looks like two orders of magnitude speed up, this will depend heavily on the number of bins however. Your timings will vary.

---

To compare to Jamie's answer I have timed the two following pieces of code. As I mainly wanted to focus on the speed of `searchsorted` vs `digitize` I pared down Jamie's code a bit. The relevant chunk is here:

```
a = np.arange(size_a)[::-1]
b = np.random.randint(0, size_a, size_b)

ja = np.take(a, np.searchsorted(a, b, side='right', sorter=a)-1)

#Compare to digitize
if ~np.allclose(ja,np.digitize(b,a)):
    print 'Comparison failed'

timing_digitize[num_a,num_b] = timeit.timeit('np.digitize(b,a)',
                      'import numpy as np; from __main__ import a, b',
                      number=3)
timing_searchsorted[num_a,num_b] = timeit.timeit('np.take(a, np.searchsorted(a, b, side="right", sorter=a)-1)',
                      'import numpy as np; from __main__ import a, b',
                      number=3)
```

This is a bit beyond my limited matplotlib ability so this is done in DataGraph. I have plotted the logarithmic ratio of `timing_digitize/timing_searchsorted` so values greater then zero `searchsorted` is faster and values less then zero `digitize` is faster. The colors also give relative speeds. For example is shows that in the top right (a = 1E6, b=1E6) `digitize` is ~300 times slower then `searchsorted` while for smaller sizes `digitize` can be up to 10x faster. The black line is roughly the break even point:

[image]
Looks like for raw speed `searchsorted` is almost always faster for large cases, but the simple syntax of `digitize` is nearly as good if the number of bins is small.

Comment: +1 - I think this is correct for all cases specified by the question: "I need the indices of the *first less than or equal occurrence* of elements of one array in another array."

Comment: I am not sure about `np.digitize`, but `np.searchsorted` does a binary search, so its strength should be large `a` arrays, rather than large `b` arrays. Setting `a = np.arange(1000)[::-1]` and `b = np.random.randint(0, 1000, 1E6)` and timing seems to confirms this.

Comment: @Jamie Thats what I discovered also, so I temporarily removed timings for your example- it was not really fair to compare the two without more examples then what I wanted to go into.

Comment: @Jamie updated the question with some relevant timings, let me know if you see any obvious flaws. I left `np.take` in as its scaling is likely `N` while `searchsorted` would be the dominant `N log(N)` operation.

Comment: I wish I could give you another +1 for the wonderful time analysis!

Answer (score 6):

This is messy, but it works:

```
>>> idx = np.argsort(a)
>>> np.take(idx, np.searchsorted(a, b, side='right', sorter=idx)-1)
array([0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3], dtype=int64)
```

If your array is always sorted, you should be able to get rid of the `argsort` call.